# IE 8 (Win XP) strange crash - Jquery and CSS "mortal" combination?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, crash

We face a very strange behaviour of I.E. 8 on a WinXP macchine.

If we set a background image onto a css and load css after setting in the header some jQuery stuff, our browser crash.

After reading some stuff onto internet, we notice that if you load jQuery before including a css that has a background image (and the image is in the filesystem at the current directory, of course!) this kind (or release) of M.S. Browser crashes.

Isn't it weird?

Someone can tell us why?

Edit:

This is .css code:

```
body { background: #650303 url('../images/bg_body.jpg') repeat-x top; }
```

This is the inclusion:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4  /strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>" lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Florence Hotel Orto de' Medici, florence hotels italy, hotels florence, hotels in florence, hotel florence, hotel in florence, florence hotel, florence, firenze, alberghi firenze, hotel firenze, hotel florenz, hotel florence, florence, florenz, hoteles florencia, accommodation florence, florence accommodation, accommodation in florence, lodging florence, florence accomodation,ponte vecchio, ponte vecchio hotel,duomo hotel, uffizi hotel, bed and breakfast, bed &amp; breakfast" />
<meta name="description" content="Florence Hotel Orto de' Medici: The central position of the Hotel, its well appointed banqueting suits, make it ideal for private functions such as business meetings, wedding receptions and cocktails parties." />
<title>Florence Hotel Orto de' Medici - <?php echo $titles["booking"][$_GET["lang"]]; ?></title>

<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="modules/mod_jweather/tmpl/mod_jweather.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="modules/mod_jflanguageselection/tmpl/mod_jflanguageselection.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/brown2011/css/template.css" type="text/css" />

<?php require_once($PHP_LIBS_FOLDER."/common_libs/u3_head.php"); ?>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/brown2011/js/unitpngfix.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE ]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/brown2011/css/IEtemplate.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

</head>
```

The problem are in that link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/brown2011/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Also, we need to see your code to know how you are applying your CSS and what other corollary methods you are using which could be causing the crash.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : ok, just done both